# mongodb aggregation compare documents and i don't want to show incompatible ones

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have three documents. First one is ***percentages***, the others ***discardeditems*** and ***filtereditems***. Sample data of these documents are as follows.

```
db = {
  "percentages": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "base": "A",
      "buy": "BUY_1",
      "sell": "SELL_1",
      "item": "ITEM_B",
      "ask": 100,
      "bid": 114,
      "percentage": 14
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "base": "B",
      "buy": "BUY_2",
      "sell": "SELL_2",
      "item": "ITEM_G",
      "ask": 50,
      "bid": 90,
      "percentage": 80
    },
    {
      "_id": 3,
      "base": "A",
      "buy": "BUY_2",
      "sell": "SELL_2",
      "item": "ITEM_G",
      "ask": 10,
      "bid": 15,
      "percentage": 50
    }
  ],
  "discardeditems": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "buy": "BUY_1",
      "sell": "SELL_1",
      "item": "ITEM_B"
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "buy": "BUY_2",
      "sell": "SELL_2",
      "item": "ITEM_G"
    }
  ],
  "filtereditems": [
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "buy": "BUY_2",
      "sell": "SELL_2",
      "item": "ITEM_G",
      "percentage": "55"
    }
  ]
}
```

Actually, I want to compare **percentages** document with ***discardeditems*** and ***filtereditems*** documents. If the buy, sell and item values in **percentages** document are equal to those in ***discardeditems*** document, I would like to add `isdiscardeditem:true` to ***percentages*** document.

And if the buy, sell, and item values in ***filtereditems*** are equal to those in ***percentages*** document and the percentage value in ***filtereditems*** document is greater than in ***percentages*** document, I no longer want to show this record.

The final version of the data I want to see should be as follows;

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "base": "A",
  "buy": "BUY_1",
  "sell": "SELL_1",
  "item": "ITEM_B",
  "ask": 100,
  "bid": 114,
  "percentage": 14,
  "isdiscarded": true
},
{
  "_id": 2,
  "base": "B",
  "buy": "BUY_2",
  "sell": "SELL_2",
  "item": "ITEM_G",
  "ask": 50,
  "bid": 90,
  "percentage": 80,   
  "isdiscarded": true   
}
```

***Percentages*** document count was three. But now i want to show two record. The other record of ***percentages*** document must not come because of the less than the percentage in ***filtereditems***.

I can add isdiscardeditem using `$lookup, $match $addFields` keyword but I have not been successful in showing two record. https://mongoplayground.net/p/_XZoqGTnIyz

How can I write?

Answer (score 1):

You can try below aggregation:

```
db.percentages.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "discardeditems",
            let: {
                item_src: "$item",
                buy_src: "$buy",
                sell_src: "$sell"
            },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $and: [
                                { $eq: [ "$$item_src", "$item" ] },
                                { $eq: [ "$$buy_src", "$buy" ] },
                                { $eq: [ "$$sell_src", "$sell" ] },
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "discarded"
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "filtereditems",
            let: {
                item_src: "$item",
                buy_src: "$buy",
                sell_src: "$sell",
                percentage_src: "$percentage"
            },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $and: [
                                { $eq: [ "$$item_src", "$item" ] },
                                { $eq: [ "$$buy_src", "$buy" ] },
                                { $eq: [ "$$sell_src", "$sell" ] },
                                { $lt: [ "$$percentage_src", { $toInt: "$percentage" } ] }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "filtered"
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            filtered: { $eq: [] }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            isdiscarded: { $gt: [ { $size: "$discarded" }, 0 ] }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            discarded: 0,
            filtered: 0
        }
    }
])
```

Please note that `percentage` fields have to have the same type so [$toInt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/) is needed for conversion.

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e4YY-C81hoC)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.